# JBOSS EAP 7.1 deployment error - Bad type on operand stack

Tags: java, exception, deployment, jboss, war

when i try to deploy a .war file on JBOSS EAP 7.1 i receive this exception:

```
"failure-description" => {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        ....
          "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration] 
          from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.xxxxxxxxxx.war\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration] 
    from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.xxxxxxxxxx.war\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration]
    from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.xxxxxxxxxx.war\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.objectMapper()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper; @30: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @30
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 8259 b700 834c 2b04 b600 8457 2ab6
    0x0000010: 0085 4d2c 2ab6 0086 b600 8757 2c2b b600
    0x0000020: 8757 2cb0                              
"}},
```

Someone other has encountered this error?
Reading other answers i configured jboss-deployment-structure.xml in this way but it not solve the problem

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<jboss-deployment-structure>  
    <deployment>  
        <exclusions>
             <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/> 
             <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider"/> 
             <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
              <module name="org.picketbox" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>  
    </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Thanks to everyone can help.